# open menu navigation drawer by default android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to know if there is a way to open the Navigation Menu by default?

My app is based on this menu, so if the navigation menu is not open by default it's look like my application is empty.

My preference is by XML.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Yes, you know how to open.But this doesn't seems logical.

Comment: I just want to show the menu by default, why it doesn't seems to be logical?

Comment: Have u ever seen any app like this?

Comment: I have to copy from other apps? If you don't think that it is logically right, you can suggest me another solution,  I'm open minded.

Comment: You can show some common things of ur app on home screen like user detail or app feature etc .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Delay is in milliseconds
static final int DRAWER_DELAY = 200;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // Building NavDrawer logic here. Just a method call would be best.
    ...
    new Handler().postDelayed(openDrawerRunnable(), DRAWER_DELAY);
}

private Runnable openDrawerRunnable() {
    return new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
    }
}
```